# How to say if an element belongs to a list in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I have this simple program that checks if an `X` element belongs to a list:

```
member2(X, [X|_]).
member2(X,[_|T]):- member2(X,T).
```

I'm trying to write it in an extended form (because in the previous way the behavior is not so clear). So I have write it in the following way:

```
member2(X, [X|_]).
member2(X,Y):- Y = [_|T],
               member2(X,T).
```

So the meaning is more clear:

I have one fact that represent the base case (the `X` element belongs to the list if it is in the head of the list).

The rule say that I have to prove two things:

1) `Y = [_|T]`. This is true because the anonymous variable `_` unifies with anything.

2) It recursively search the element `X` in the tail list.

Ok, I think my reasoning is correct but this second version of the program don't work! I think that maybe the problem could be in the `Y = [_|T]` section

Comment: This program seems to work as expected for me on SWI-PL, what specifically is going wrong? Are you getting an error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your program is fine, in both forms. Here yet another way to (re)write it

```
member2(X, [Y|Ys]) :-
    X = Y ; member2(X, Ys).
```

Comment: Okkk...thanks...only one things...in this example X is unified to Y...so it means that X variable contain the head character of the [Y|Ys] list?

Comment: Tnx...I have posted another question today...I am going crazy...if you can help me...

Answer (score 0):

I guess the textbook example of **checking** for a member is:

```
member_check(X, [X|Tail]). % or [X|_] to avoid the warning
member_check(X, [Y|Tail]) :- X \= Y, member_check(X, Tail).
```

which would probably be clearer than your second attempt?